# Javascript/jQuery hover on separate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, hover, joomla1.5

I have a strange problem, stemming from a layout that I cannot change to better solve this.

Basically I have a menu like so:

```
<div id="hornav">
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item1">link</li>
    <li class="item2">link</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I have drop downs separated like so:

```
 <div class="dropdowns">
     <div id="ditem1" class="dropdown-div">content</div>
     <div id="ditem2" class="dropdown-div">content</div>
 </div>
```

What i need to do is make the links hover to show the container. I can do this but I also need to make it so if I move my mouse over the drop down that shows, it does not disappear.

*Because of the way the site is running, and what tools I am limited by I **cannot** make the dropdowns inside of the li elements (It is dynamically generated by the CMS, without any options)* - This point is extremely important.

Right now this is the javascript code i am using. It functions to an extent, though IT is very buggy (If i hover over the contained element, then hover back it vanishes). This code may be slightly outdated as I have been gradually trying multiple methods, and reading up on this problem with little success.

```
function dropdown(event,passDown){
    var classes=$(passDown).attr('class').split(' ');
    for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
        if(classes[i].indexOf('item')!=-1){
            var classId=classes[i];
        }
    }
    var elem=$('#d'+classId);
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!elem.hasClass('active')){
        $('#hornav li.active,.dropdown-div.active').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('#d'+classId).addClass('active');
        $(passDown).parent().addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('#hornav li.active,.dropdown-div.active').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
}
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hornav>ul>li[class*="item"]:not(.item20)').each(function(){ //trigger all drop down links
        $(this).hover(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log(event);
            var setIt=this;
            if(event.relatedTarget.id.indexOf('ditem')==-1){
                dropdown(event,this);
            }
        });
    });
    $('.dropdowns .dropdown-div').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log(event);
            var setIt=this;
            //if(event.offsetParent.className.indexOf('item')==-1){
                $('#hornav li.active,.dropdown-div.active').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
            //}
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:

We have decided to take another approach and are going to use clicks instead of hovers witch will not cause the problem.

I will leave this open for now, as it seems like a question that could help others out.

EDIT 2:

Never solved this and ended up coming up with another completely different solution. However I feel this question may help people in the future so I will leave it open if anyone wants to answer it.

Comment: Why don't you use Joomla's menu module? With that, you can easily create horizontal dropdown menus just using CSS.

Comment: at worst just create a template override and throw in your javascript... or just place it in the template

Comment: It is already in the template, however since I have to load multiple modules into the drop downs and not standard menu items the menu module does not do what I need it to do. This is such a simple concept and I have done much more complex things before but doing a full template override is 20 extra steps just to set it up and will probably get me to nearly the same setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each child element, fire the events on the parent element:

```
jQuery(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).parent().trigger(e.type);
});
```

Comment: Old question but thank you for your answer. Thinking about this this can work but not in that code. Since there are totally separated `parent` will not work. With the use of data attributes and id, it could target the proper drop down.

Comment: I like to browse SO looking for interesting questions, and yours piqued my interest.  I wasn't sure exactly your HTML, so I assumed parent but yes, it could easily target another element and data-attributes would be a great way to identify the target.